# Dynamic CRM 2011 SOAP RetrieveMultiple xml for querying from two table

Tags: soap, dynamics-crm-2011

I was stuck with Dynamics CRM 2011. I want to create SOAP RetrieveMultiple xml which will fetched the data from two different table using inner join on the basis foreign key.

I have tried many ways but unable to get success.

For my scenarios let's say table A and B is there. 
A -- (id, name, address_id)
B -- (srno, address_id, area, city, zip)

Now, I want to get the details from table A & B based on below query,

select A.id, A.name, B.area, B.city, B.zip 
from A
INNER JOIN B
ON A.address_id = B.address_id

I'm totally new with Dynamics CRM 2011.

It would be great if you can share some valuable examples.

Thanks in advance.

My SOAP XML

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
    <s:Body>
        <RetrieveMultiple xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services' xmlns:i='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'>
            <query i:type='a:QueryExpression' xmlns:a='http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts'>
                <a:EntityName>A</a:EntityName>
                <a:ColumnSet>
                    <a:AllColumns>false</a:AllColumns>
                    <a:Columns xmlns:b='http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays'>
                        <b:string>name</b:string>
                        <b:string>area</b:string>
                        <b:string>city</b:string>
                        <b:string>zip</b:string>
                    </a:Columns>
                </a:ColumnSet>
                <a:Distinct>address_id</a:Distinct>

                <a:LinkEntities>
                    <a:LinkEntity>
                        <a:LinkFromAttributeName>address_id</a:LinkFromAttributeName>
                        <a:LinkFromEntityName>A</a:LinkFromEntityName>
                        <a:LinkToEntityName>B</a:LinkToEntityName>
                        <a:LinkToAttributeName>address_id</a:LinkToAttributeName>
                        <a:JoinOperator>Inner</a:JoinOperator>
                        <a:LinkCriteria>
                            <a:FilterOperator>And</a:FilterOperator>
                            <a:Conditions>
                                <a:Condition>           
                                    <a:AttributeName>address_id</a:AttributeName>
                                    <a:Operator>Equal</a:Operator>
                                    <a:Values>
                                        <a:Value xsi:type="xsd:string">123454</q1:Value>
                                    </a:Values>
                                </a:Condition>
                            </a:Conditions>
                        </a:LinkCriteria>
                    </a:LinkEntity>
                </a:LinkEntities>
            </query>
        </RetrieveMultiple>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Regards,
Ashish Mishra

Answer (score 0):

You can only do inner joins between related entities (1:N), `where a.Id = b.aId` you need to Retrieve A records from that address and B records from that address.

Comment: I've edited my question with sample SOAP xml which I'm using to retrieve the data from the DCRM-20111

Comment: So you are retrieving the A's entities where address is '123454'